# Regex rule in an NGinx Config to only compare against the first url param

Tags: regex, nginx

Here is an example of our current Nginx rule that will redirect some traffic from one base domain to another (result of a DNS Migration):

```
location ~* /(var1|var2|var3) {
    rewrite ^ http://newurl.com$uri? permanent;
}
```

So using the url above the following url: `oldurl.com/var1/foo`
properly get redirected to: `newurl.com/var1/foo`

Using this approach `oldurl.com/foo` currently does not redirect to the new domain which is as designed and what we want.

However the problem we are now having is that if any keywords that are found in the location statement are used anywhere in the URL then it get's redirected.  We only want to pattern match against variables found in the first `/###/` folder of the url sequence.

In other words we want `oldurl.com/var1/foo`
to redirect but not `oldurl.com/foo/var1`

Given our current regex rule it finds var1 in the url (even though it is in the 2nd position) and redirects.
In other words: `oldurl.com/foo/var1`
redirects to `newurl.com/foo/var1`
but we don't want it to.

My regex is just not that spiffy to pattern match against only the first block of `/###/` code.  Can someone help me with the proper regex/nginx statement?

Answer (score 0):

It's a regular expression so you need to anchor it to the beginning of the url path with `^` like this:

```
location ~* ^/(var1|var2|var3) {
    rewrite ^ http://newurl.com$uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `return 301 $scheme://newurl.com$uri;`